# Creating a shared folder in a non-windows machine programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, samba

I am trying to use the NetShareAdd() Windows API function to create remotely a shared folder in a Linux box. I have a folder shared using samba and I am able to create directories remotely right there; but I always get ACCESS_DENIED when I try to create a network share in such machine.

Do you know if is this possible? If it is, do you have some ideas of how to make that work?

This is a small test on it:

```
int main()
{
    SHARE_INFO_2 sh;
    sh.shi2_netname = L"shr004x";
    sh.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE;
    sh.shi2_remark = L"This is a shared test";
    sh.shi2_permissions = ACCESS_ALL;
    sh.shi2_max_uses = 17;
    sh.shi2_current_uses = 1;
    sh.shi2_path = L"/mnt/Storage/Test/test001"; //No matter what I put here, I always get access denied (5)
    sh.shi2_passwd = NULL;
    DWORD hr = ::NetShareAdd(L"172.16.212.40", 2, (LPBYTE) &sh, NULL);
    cout << hr << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Creating a new Samba share on a linux box generally involves editing configuration files and restarting the Samba service.  Now to be completely honest I have no idea if what you're trying to do is possible or even recommended -- but I really * **really** * doubt it is either possible or recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Disk Operator privilege (SeDiskOperatorPrivilege) and Samba configured to allow creating shares.

See smb.conf(5) manual page for 'add share command' option description.